# In the 2005 King Kong movie, what did the native old woman try to say to Ann Darrow?

Tags: king-kong, king-kong-2005

In the movie *King Kong* (2005) when Ann Darrow was captured, and all her ship mates were being massacred by the natives, an old woman tried to say things in an unknown language while looking directly into her eyes.

What was she trying to say? Was she trying to warn her or was it some kind of ritual? Does anyone know?

Comment: I thought my answer to this was pretty nice. Is there anything you think I should have addressed in order to secure the acceptance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've checked the shooting script and there doesn't appear to be any explanation, so it's likely it's deliberately left up to the viewer to decide.

The natives seem to believe that Ann's golden hair will appease Kong more than a normal native girl. It's likely the Witch Doctor is saying something about how Ann should be sacrificed instead (it's what the Witch Doctor in the 1933 version of *King Kong* believed), but unless Peter Jackson says something in his commentary or elsewhere, I don't think anyone can say for sure.

Answer (score 4):

The film's [original screenplay](https://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/King_Kong__2005_.pdf) has the scene in full, along with the phonetic translation, but alas, not the actual wording.

> The NATIVES SHRIEK. One of the SAILORS is DRAGGED forward, his HEAD pushed against a FLAT STONE SLAB, and CLUBBED TO DEATH.
>
> ANGLE ON: In the midst of the CONFUSION, JACK sees the OLD SHA-WOMAN screaming at ANN. She starts chanting with rising HYSTERICS ...
>
> **SHA-WOMAN:** (chanting) *Larri yu sano korê ... Kweh yonê kah‘weh ad-larr ... torê Kông!*

As far as I can tell this appears to be a derivative of Malay. Some of the words are familiar (korê = *caused*, kah‘weh = *the time has come*, torê Kông = *Kong (the big man) is coming*) whereas other parts of it seem to be gibberish.

The general implication of this imprecation seems to be that Ann and the crew have caused Kong to turn up and that she's the traditional sacrifice.